# Создание .doc средствами Java на Android

Tags: android, java

Суть простая, программа делает расчеты , в итоге получается то что надо бы сохранить в .doc ( оформление по госту , и делаться должно по волшебному нажатию заветной клавиши , форматирование не пару строчек, а с таблицей и т.д. ).

Все хорошо кроме последнего пункта... сохранение в формат ворда ( или другой документ который сможет пользователь далекий от современной технике скушать принтеру ).

С заказчиком договоренность была о сохранении на SD карту.
Кто-то может подсказать где копать или дать добрый совет ?

Comment: Не знаю, подойдёт ли для андроида, но есть такая Java-библиотека:
http://java2word.blogspot.ru/p/documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

klopp верную библиотеку подсказал, будет работать и на андроид. Очень хорошая документация на эту библиотеку! Сам работал с ней несколько лет назад!